# PageTransforme: наложение новой страницы поверх старой

Tags: android-viewpager, android

Добрый день.
Делаю свой кастомный **ViewPager.PageTransformer**.
Пытаюсь сделать наложение наложение новой страницы с индексом **i**, поверх страницы с индексом **i -1**. Причем страница с индексом **i-1** не должна двигаться.

Пришел к такому результату

```
public static class StackPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer
{

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position)
    {
        final int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
        if (position > 0 && position < 1)
        {
            view.setTranslationX(pageWidth * -position);
        }
    }
}
```

Но там происходит все с точностью да наоборот. Страница с индексом **i-1** уезжает со страницы с индексом **i**. Я что-то туплю.
**UPD 1.05.2015:** проблема все еще актуальна.

Comment: У меня как-то в голове не складывается. Какое натуральное число может быть одновременно больше 0 и меньше 1?

Comment: @Lucky_spirit >float position

Comment: @Andreich, точно, не обратил внимания. По рекомендациям Java всегда у типа float добавляю f в конце. То есть в моём коде были бы 0.0f и 1.0f.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit да это понятно все. Проблема я вно не в этих константах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел решение. Вот то, что я хотел.

```
public class StackPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        view.setTranslationX(position > 0 ? 0f : -view.getWidth() * position);
    }

}
```

**UPD:** для корректной работы данной реализации, при добавлении PageTransformer нужно послать **false** в качестве первого аргумента

```
setPageTransformer(false, new StackPageTransformer());
```